# getopt_long_only() not working

Tags: c, getopt-long

I need to check the following arguments:

```
  ./centro -n CD1 –cp 100000 –i 100000 –t 30 –s 1000 –p 11111
```

And they can come in any order. I have the following code:

```
void checkParameters (int argc, char** argv, center_data* info) {

    int opt = 0;

    const char* const short_options = "n:i:t:s:p:a:";

    static struct option long_options[] = {
                    {"cp", 1, NULL, 'a'},
                    {0, 0 , 0, 0}
    };

    if(argc != 13)
            error("Error en numero de argumentos \n");

    while(opt != -1){

        opt = getopt_long_only(argc, argv, short_options, long_options, NULL);

        switch (opt){   

            case 'n':
                strcpy(info->center_name, optarg);
                break;

            case 'a':
                printf("el optgar %s \n", optarg);
                info->cap_max = atoi(optarg);
                if (!(38000 <= info->cap_max && info->cap_max <= 3800000))
                    error("Error en la capacidad maxima del centro. \n");

                break;

            case 'i':
                printf("el optgar %s \n", optarg);
                info->stock = atoi(optarg);
                break;

            case 't':
                printf("el optgar %s \n", optarg);
                info->response_time = atoi(optarg);
                if (!(0 <= info->response_time && info->response_time <= 180))
                    error("Error en el tiempo de respuesta \n");

                break;

            case 's':
                printf("el optgar %s \n", optarg);
                info->supply = atoi(optarg);
                if(!(0 <= info->supply && info->supply <= 10000))
                    error("Error en la cantidad de suministro \n");

                break;

            case 'p':
                printf("el optgar %s \n", optarg);
                info->port = atoi(optarg);
                if (0 <= info->port && info->port <=1023)
                    error("Error: se esta utilizando un puerto bien conocido");

                break;

            case -1:
                printf("caso -1\n");
                break;

            default:
                printf("caso default\n");
                abort();
        }
    }

    if (!(0 <= info->stock && info->stock <= info->cap_max))
        error("Error en el inventario actual de la bomba \n");
}
```

The thing is, it enters first the n case and then the -1 and it exits. Which makes no sense. I see no error in the use of getopt_long_only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the different length of the dashes in:

```
./centro -n CD1 –cp 100000 –i 100000 –t 30 –s 1000 –p 11111
```

The first one is the *minus* character. The others are longer. That's the problem.

Comment: I see, it was a really silly mistake then. thanks letting me see the error.

Answer (score 0):

sir you are not using minus for all the arguments

try this command:

```
./centro -a 100 -n 100000 -i 100000 -t 30 -s 1000 -p 11111
```

btw can you please let us know which character it is, i could not find any such on my keyboard.